# IR/Depth stream from a Logitech Brio 4k stream on Windows

Tags: c++, winapi, video, sensors, ms-media-foundation

I'm trying to access the IR/Depth stream on a Logitech Brio 4K Stream on Windows. Unfortunately the device only enumerates as video device and not as sensor. I'm using the function MFEnumDeviceSources with the attributes MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE, MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE_VIDCAP_GUID for the video device and in addition the attribute MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE_VIDCAP_CATEGORY, KSCATEGORY_VIDEO_CAMERA to enumerate sensor cameras. This works fine for the DELL built-in camera on my laptop, but not for the Brio.
The Brio Video camera lists about 442 streams, but none of them seems to be the depth stream.
I was just wondering how windows activate the depth camera when doing hello.
I looked into the ksproperty set KSPROPERTYSETID_ExtendedCameraControl, but I'm unable to read the properties, and get always wrong argument, even I queried first the size of the required output.

Any idea or help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

```
    IMFAttributes* pAttributes = nullptr;
    MFCreateAttributes(&pAttributes, 2);
    pAttributes->SetGUID(MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE,MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE_VIDCAP_GUID);
    pAttributes->SetGUID(MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE_VIDCAP_CATEGORY,KSCATEGORY_VIDEO_CAMERA);
    MFEnumDeviceSources(pAttributes, &ppCameras, &cCameras); // Brio listed here as video camera

    IMFAttributes* pAttributes = nullptr;
    MFCreateAttributes(&pAttributes, 2);
    pAttributes->SetGUID(MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE,MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE_VIDCAP_GUID);
    pAttributes->SetGUID(MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE_VIDCAP_CATEGORY,KSCATEGORY_SENSOR_CAMERA);
    MFEnumDeviceSources(pAttributes, &ppSensors, &cSensors); // but not listed here as sensor

    KSPROPERTY p;
    ZeroMemory(&p, sizeof(p));
    p.Set = KSPROPERTYSETID_ExtendedCameraControl;
    p.Id = KSPROPERTY_CAMERACONTROL_EXTENDED_FACEAUTH_MODE;
    p.Flags = KSPROPERTY_TYPE_GET;
    pKsControl->KsProperty((PKSPROPERTY)&p, sizeof(p), nullptr, 0, &dwReturned); // works and returns ERROR_MORE_DATA

    BYTE* d = new BYTE[dwReturned];
    ZeroMemory(d, dwReturned);
    hpKsControl->KsProperty((PKSPROPERTY)&p, sizeof(p), d, dwReturned, &dwReturned); // does not work here, invalid argument
```

Comment: Microsoft exposes sensor streams to UWP apps via sensor API, but Win32 apps have just video from underlying kernel streaming driver forwarded trough frame server service.

Comment: Sorry to ask again, I thought when using IMFMediaSource and a MFCreateSourceReaderFromMediaSource I will access the frameserver. But when I query for streams using GetNativeMediaType, I do not see any IR/Depth stream.

Comment: Right, that's what I am saying: Source Reader API won't give you access to non-video streams. Microsoft exposes those only via [`Windows.Media.Capture.Frames`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.frames?view=winrt-22621) and friends. [`InfraredMediaFrame`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.frames.infraredmediaframe?view=winrt-22621) & [`DepthMediaFrame`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.frames.depthmediaframe?view=winrt-22621).

Comment: Any chance to get access to this, when using native Win32 API?

Comment: There is no documented way that I am aware of and I prefer to not comment on [undocumented](https://alax.info/blog/1911). I would probably rather suggest to try using   `Windows.Media.Capture.Frames` from UWP app, esp. such as C++/WinRT app, even if it would require app packaging, and forward the data to Win32 app then.

Comment: Thanks, looks like Windows.Media.Capture.Frames is working, but I will need it native anyway. But it's a good start to investigate this. 
I also noted the missing documentation and the Windows Hello Bring Up guide isn't helpful either :-(
Seems to be the case "MS knows better for you"

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `Windows.Media.Capture` namespace is available to classic desktop applications. *"I will need it native anyway"* - The Windows Runtime *is* native.

Comment: I'm getting closer to it. It's barely documented, but you can use the Media Foundation interfaces. I will post the solution here as soon as I got it working.

Comment: BTW which model is this, is it [960-001105](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/products/webcams/brio-4k-hdr-webcam.960-001105.html) and it has both IR and Depth selectable streams?

Comment: I'm using a Logitech Brio Stream 4K Type code 960-001194. Which seems to be the recent model (as of March 2023). The visible camera features from right to left, white LED, RGB camera, IR camera IR flash. Means the RGB and IR camera are using different HW and optics. But I wasn't able to stream RGB and IR at the same time.
Other hello cameras (as my dell build in) showing up as camera and sensor in the device manager. they can be queried using the same approach, but you have to enumerate the senso camera separate from the video camera.

Answer (score 2):

The Infrared stream is also accessible from Windows media foundation. Here are the steps, which worked for me:

1. create a media source

```
    IMFActivate* device; // your device from enumeration
    IMFMediaSourceEx* mediaSource = nullptr;
    device->ActivateObject(__uuidof(IMFMediaSourceEx), (void**)&mediaSource);
```

2. create a presentation descriptor from the media source

```
    IMFPresentationDescriptor* presentationDesc = nullptr;
    mediaSource->CreatePresentationDescriptor(&presentationDesc);
```

3. enumerate available streams

```
    DWORD cDesc = 0;
    presentationDesc->GetStreamDescriptorCount(&cDesc);
    for (DWORD i = 0; i < cDesc; i++)
    {
        IMFStreamDescriptor* pStream = nullptr;
        presentationDesc->GetStreamDescriptorByIndex(i, &selected, &pStream);
        presentationDesc->DeselectStream(i); // just making sure no stream is selected
    ...
```

4. enumerate media types per stream

```
    IMFMediaTypeHandler* pHandler = nullptr;
    pStream->GetMediaTypeHandler(&pHandler);
    DWORD cMediaType = 0;
    pHandler->GetMediaTypeCount(&cMediaType);
    for (DWORD j = 0; j < cMediaType; j++)
    {
        IMFMediaType* pMediaType = nullptr;
        pHandler->GetMediaTypeByIndex(j, &pMediaType);
```

5. You can now read the media type and all information like image width, image height, frames per second and format

```
    MFGetAttributeSize(pMediaType, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, &imageWidth, &imageHeight);
    MFGetAttributeRatio(pMediaType, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, &fpsNumerator, &fpsDenominator);
    pMediaType->GetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, &imageFormat);
```

6. The IR stream shall have the media format(s)
   MFVideoFormat_L8 - infrared image
   MFVideoFormat_L16 - infrared image
   MFVideoFormat_D16 - depth image
7. Activate your prefered stream and media type

```
    presentationDesc->SelectStream(i);
    pHandler->SetCurrentMediaType(pMediaType);
```

8. Use the proper stream index when creating the source reader

```
    MFCreateAttributes(&pAttributes, 2);
    pAttributes->SetUnknown(MF_SOURCE_READER_ASYNC_CALLBACK, this);
    pAttributes->SetUINT32(MF_SOURCE_READER_DISCONNECT_MEDIASOURCE_ON_SHUTDOWN, TRUE);
    MFCreateSourceReaderFromMediaSource(mediaSource, pAttributes, &reader);
```

9. select the stream for the source reader

```
    DWORD streamid = 0;
    pStream->GetStreamIdentifier(&streamId);
    reader->SetStreamSelection(streamId, TRUE);
    reader->SetCurrentMediaType(streamId, nullptr, pMediaType);
```

10. when reading the frames use the correct stream id

```
    reader->ReadSample(_streamId, 0, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
```

The posted code snippets above are not fully complete. You need to add error handling and clean up (releasing resources).

Comment: This is a good find, thanks for sharing!